# How do I stop a YouTube live stream?

Tags: youtube, youtube-live

YouTube's instructions state that to stop the stream:

> To stop, simply stop streaming from your encoder. YouTube will detect
>   that you stopped sending content and stop the stream for you.

When I stop streaming from [OBS](https://obsproject.com/), the YouTube stream goes offline as expected. However, the stream archive doesn't appear in my video manager and when I refresh the "Stream now" page the "Elapsed time" still continues.

To get my stream archived and show up in my video manager I went:

**Stream now → Basic info → Advanced settings → Live Control room → Stop streaming**.

Is this the proper way to stop streaming on YouTube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out YouTube is smarter than that, it actually doesn't end your stream right away, because it thinks that you may have network or software problems that would be causing your stream to stop and YouTube waits a while to give you an option to resume your stream once you've solved your problem. If you don't have any problems and decide to end the stream, just stop streaming in your streaming software and wait a few minutes.

Comment: What if I don't want to wait until it understands I'm not streaming anymore? What if I want to cut and have the video saved immediately to start another stream?

Answer (score 1):

### Use the "End Stream" button in YouTube Studio

Before I start streaming, I open up the page for the stream in YouTube Studio. If you're in YouTube proper, you'll need to get into YTS by clicking on your profile image on the top right and then going to "YouTube Studio". Once you're there, look for "Create" > "Go Live" in the upper right. This should bring up a list of your future (or ongoing) streams, where you can get to the full page for your current stream.

This page can be pretty helpful (which is why I recommend keeping it open while streaming), since it allows you to preview your video feed before you go live or get helpful statistics such as how many people are watching at any moment.

If you haven't publicly started the stream, you'll see a button in the top right to "Go Live". If you're already streaming, you'll instead see an "End Stream" button:

[image: "End stream" in upper right]
[Screenshot by Tosh](https://dev.to/toshvelaga/how-to-livestream-to-youtube-using-the-youtube-live-streaming-api-4klp)

If you just stop streaming from your streaming software and close the tab, the stream *won't* be ended, which is helpful if you're having technical problems. For example, I was live-streaming an outdoor event and halfway through there was thunder and lightning and everything had to be moved inside. I had to shut down the computer running my streaming software but with minimal disruption I was able to resume the same stream when I was indoors.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube Events (legacy) supports this.

1. Go to **YouTube Studio** → **Manage**.
2. Click on **Events** on the bottom right.

[image]

3. An Event window will open. Click **Edit** next to your streaming video.

[image]

4. Click the **Live Control Room** tab on the next screen.

[image]

5. Here, you can see the **Stop Streaming** button.

[image]

[image]

6. Now, back on YouTube Studio, you can see the streaming has been stopped.

[image]

Note that this will be **working until 15 April 2020**, and since YouTube Events are going away, this might not be available, but then it may be shown in YouTube Studio. Right now (15 Apr 2020), there's no option in YouTube Studio to turn streaming off. YouTube thinks that streaming may be stopped due to an error at your end, and it might get resolved within a couple of minutes. However, it eventually ends the stream at a later time.