# Forcefully end youtube live stream

Tags: youtube-live

How to end youtube live stream? Usually when started a live stream through YouTube Studio, the streaming starts but there's no option to stop it. If streaming through another service such as Zoom, ending the meeting does not turnoff stream.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop a YouTube live stream?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103558/how-do-i-stop-a-youtube-live-stream)